# Importing Python Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

Given the following code in **foo.py**:

```
class Error(Exception):
pass

class UnexpectedParameterType(Error):
pass

class Human(models.Manager):

    def create_human(self, name):

        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise UnexpectedParameterType

        human = Human(name = name)
        return human
```

Do I absolutely have to explicitly import my exception class in **bar.py** so that I can catch the exception being thrown? Like this:

```
from foo import UnexpectedParameterType, Human

human = Human()
try:
    human.create_human(123)
except UnexpectedParameterType:
    return "Cannot create human."
```

What I am hinting at here is being able to do something like this:

```
from foo import Human

[...]

except Human.UnexpectedParameterType:
    return "Cannot create human."
```

All answers are much appreciated, thanks! Feel free to share your personal best practices for dealing with exceptions in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do `Human.UnexpectedParameterType` because `Human` doesn't have an attribute called `UnexpectedParameterType`.

This is why you generally want to do `import foo` not `from foo import ...`. It's easier to trace what things go to if you do it that way.

What you COULD do is to create a base class that has its own exceptions attached to it. This could be something like

```
# foo.py

class Human(object):
    class Error(Exception):
        pass

    class UnexpectedParameterType(Error):
        pass

    def throw_bad_parm(self):
        raise self.UnexpectedParameterType

    # the rest of your function in Human
```

DEMO:

```
import foo

a = foo.Human()
try:
    a.throw_bad_parm()
except foo.Human.UnexpectedParameterType as e:
    print("You can't do that because of {!r}".format(e))

# You can't do that because of UnexpectedParameterType()
```

This works in much the same way as `@staticmethod` does -- you're bundling things that are logically part of your code in other classes, even though they don't rely on those classes to operate. In this way you might do something like:

```
class HTTPHandler(object):
    class Exception404(Exception): pass
    class Exception403(Exception): pass
    ...
```

Comment: That's what I thought but if you recall in Django, you can do something like: MyModel.DoesNotExist where MyModel is a class and not a file. That is basically what I am trying to do in my code as well.

Comment: @heapoverflow you can't put blocks of text in comments. [gisthub](https://gist.github.com/) is good for that

Comment: Also, I see you put a class inside another class. Is that legal in Python?

Comment: @heapoverflow classes are objects. In fact almost everything is an object. You can put objects in objects in objects in objects. It's no different from putting functions in functions, or passing functions to functions. You can even put a class in a function, though I don't know why you would.

Comment: I see... but don't you need to raise your exception there with parentheses, like this: raise self.UnexpectedParameterType() ?

(Since it's a class...?)

Comment: @heapoverflow Nope, for the same reason you don't have to use parentheses any other time you raise exceptions. You CAN, to give it a custom error message, because the `BaseException` type (from which all other exceptions are children) supports this.

Comment: @heapoverflow to showcase that: https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/d57cecf6d9e783a76c0e

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `Human.UnexpectedParameterType`, because `UnexpectedParameterType` isn't an attribute on the `Human` class; it is part of the `foo` module. You could do something like this

```
import foo

human = foo.Human()
try:
    human.create_human(123)
except foo.UnexpectedParameterType:
    return "Cannot create human."
```

Otherwise, yes, you do have to explicitly import it.

---

In this specific case, however, Python already has an exception to represent bad types: the `TypeError`. So, instead, you could raise `TypeError`, and later catch `TypeError`. (`TypeError` is a built-in type, so you don't explicitly import it.)